# Why am I getting this UnicodeEncodeError when I am inserting into the MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, encoding

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I changed my database default to be utf-8, and not "latin"....but this error still occurs. why?

This is in **my.cnf**. Am I doing this wrong? I just want EVERYTHING TO BE UTF-8.

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: On which file/line this error occurs?

Comment: It occurs on the line that I "INSERT" into the database.

Comment: Have you tried dropping and recreating the DB since you changed the default?

Comment: no, I have too much data in there.

Comment: Show real code that produces the error.

Comment: Actually, show the whole model code. 99 times out of 100, in Django this error is caused by a faulty `__unicode__` method in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an exception from Python then it's nothing to do with MySQL -- the error happens before the expression is sent to MySQL.  I would presume that the MySQLdb driver doesn't handle unicode.

If you are dealing with the raw MySQLdb interface this will be somewhat annoying (database wrappers like SQLAlchemy will handle this stuff for you), but you might want to create a function like this:

```
def exec_sql(conn_or_cursor, sql, *args, **kw):
    if hasattr(conn_or_cursor):
        cursor = conn_or_cursor.cursor()
    else:
        cursor = conn_or_cursor
    cursor.execute(_convert_utf8(sql), *(_convert_utf8(a) for a in args),
                   **dict((n, _convert_utf8(v)) for n, v in kw.iteritems()))
    return cursor

def _convert_utf8(value):
    if isinstance(value, unicode):
        return value.encode('utf8')
    else:
        return value
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I do the INSERT statement. In Django, this is...music.save()

Answer (score 2):

MySQLdb.connect(read_default_*) options won't set the character set from default-character-set.  You will need to set this explicitly:

```
MySQLdb.connect(..., charset='utf8')
```

Or the equivalent setting in your django databases settings.